# Organizing Android Code around DB Access

Tags: android, database, unit-testing

Some backstory on my applications code organization:

Right now I'm kind of using a ad-hoc ORM for DB access, where each table is split up into a model (just a plain Java class not inheriting from any Android components) which covers normal CRUD activities.
I'm not using a content provider as all this data is private to the application.

I'm keeping a singleton of my databaseopenhelper, and the application context in my application's Application class

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
  private static Context mContext;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); // Subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
  }

  public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
  }
```

All activities that touch the db open the database onResume, and close it onPause.

This seemed to be working fine until I started unit testing, when I ran into the first problem with using singletons - breaking encapsulation (specifically not being able use RenamingDelegatingContext to test with a specific test database).

So,

1) Something tells me if I can't unit test properly, my architecture is bunk - but I can't think of a better way to do this (short of passing context and dbhelpers explicitly - which is a pain)

2) If it is not an entirely crazy idea, what would be the best way to go about unit testing this setup?

Comment: Why would you need to save the context into the application's static variable? Any activity is a Context, so you can get it any time by `this`..

Comment: What stops you from creating `DatabaseHelper` in every activity? All you have to do is to create an abstract activity class and re-use it's `onCreate` in every other activity

Comment: @denis.solonenko
I'm saving context to static variable as my model classes are just plain Java classes and don't inherit from any Android components. Like I was saying, I could pass my context in, but I feel like there's probably a more efficient way.

Nothing stops me from creating a new `DatabaseHelper` but object creation AFAIK is expensive, so why bother creating/destroying it needlessly if I'm only ever going to have one instance of it?

Comment: I'd be passing context to my model classes especially if it removes dependency on the global singleton and simplify testing. creating objects is not that expensive - surely you can afford one more object for every activity :)

Comment: I'm just going by this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html - since you shouldn't have more than one instance at any given moment, I feel like it falls under the definition of creating unnecessary objects.